# WordPress Multisite (Network) some site users added to main site users list as subscriber

Tags: multisite, users, network-admin

We have installed WordPress Multisite (Network) and created some sites.

On the main site admin > users, it displays some users from other sites listed as subscriber user.

Please advice how this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behaviour.

From the codex on [Multisite Network Administration](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration):

> By design, all users who are added to your network will have subscriber access to all sites on your network. To allocate a different default role for users on individual sites, you must use a plugin, such as [Multisite User Management](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management).

Comment: I am afraid why some users added and others not?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is possible as there is only one user table in the database